# Как вывести элемент из базы данных MySQL с помощью PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть код

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mybase');

function getsql($connect) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $cat = mysqli_fetch_all($res, 
    MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $cat;
}
$cat = getsql($connect);
print_r($cat);
echo $cat[1];
?>
```

он выводит на странице следующее:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [name] => testname 
        [nicename] => testnika 
        [email] => mail@mail.ru 
        [pass] => dfgfdgdfgdfgdf 
    ) 
)
```

Хочу вывести из этого массива например name, но мне ничего не выводит. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: `print_r($cat[0]['name']);`, можно как-то так `foreach($cat as $temp_cat){print_r($temp_cat['name']);}`

Answer (score 0):

Из базы данных вы получаете массив, в котором находится еще один массив с данными отдельной строки в базе  данных. Правильно будет перебирать эти данные в цикле foreach и уже в нем совершать с ними нужные вам действия, к примеру, выводить на экран:

```
<?php
$connect=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'mybase');

function getsql($connect) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `test_table`";
    $res = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
    $cat = mysqli_fetch_all($res,
        MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $cat;
}
$cat = getsql($connect);

foreach ($cat as $item) {
    echo 'Name: ' . $item['name'];
}
?>
```